Receiver tracking problems
The medium wave band, in which AM is still dominant, has a very high ratio of Fmax to Fmin, unlike most other radio bands. The exact edges vary from country but compare 510-1650 kHz to say 144 to 148 MHz which is the 2 meter ham band. This meant that normal superhet receivers had ganged tuning for the antenna and the RF and local oscillator.
455 kHz was and still is a common IF.  Tracking was a problem but most sets performed OK across the MW broadcast band. An IF of 2 MHz would still be out of band and form the basis of a wideband AM tuner where better fidelity on local stations would be expected and poorer SNR on distant stations would follow.

How does tracking accuracy relate to IF frequency?
Does lower make tracking easier?
Does higher make tracking harder?
Is there a simple equation that predicts this?


This is an interesting academic question. I'd like to include this link from EESE to this topic.

Does lower make tracking easier? <-- what do you mean by "lower"?

@ Andy aka .If the tracking error is too great then I would want a lower Q front end to allow single knob tuning .The     ganged  variable caps all have  equal capacitance sections  and the osc can have a padder and a trimmer .I want to try wideband for better sound quality on local stations


How does tracking accuracy relate to IF frequency?

A zero-I.F. receiver gives a very simple tracking solution, whereas a higher-frequency I.F. makes tracking more difficult. AM broadcast band receivers using 455 kHz I.F. would be in the "difficult" class.

Is there a simple equation that predicts this?

Some solutions solve tracking with custom-cut variable capacitor plates. If done exactly properly, tracking is solved. For example, one polyvaricon variable capacitor has two sections driven by one shaft: 145pf would tune the RF stage while 65pf would tune the local oscillator's frequency. Another example having 4-gangs (20pf + 365pf + 180pf + 20pf:


Where ganged variable capacitor sections are identical, the solution is more complex. One solution does a crude 3rd-order tracking with a simple coupling capacitor (C3, below) that reduces local-oscillator maximum capacitance. At only three frequencies in that wide bandwidth, tracking is exact. L1 and L2 have different values. Tracking of the example circuit is within one AM channel (10kHz) over a band span of 550kHz - 2400kHz:

There were sometimes trimmer capacitors that were not ganged - these adjusted tracking mostly at the high-frequency end of the band (less-so at the band's bottom-end). These trimmers were not user-available, often part of the variable capacitor frame (C4 below, 6pf). It was adjusted once, at the factory.
There was a third tracking problem - that of aligning station frequency against the front-panel frequency scale.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For those who like to knob-twiddle, a separate variable capacitor for local oscillator and for the R.F. gain stage is acceptable. In an earlier age, this solution was common, with multiple front end controls. If an external antenna was used, this is a versatile solution - easing the designer's headache.

What a nice answer .I wonder what the tracking error would be with different IF like say 265Kc and 2Mc

In the vacuum tube era, the standard for AM automobile radio IFs was 262.5 kHz. Auto radios needed more RF gain than domestic MW radios to make up for the low effective height of an auto radio antenna, so they had an extra tuned RF stage.
A universal issue with superhets is image rejection. The higher the IF frequency, the easier it is to get good image rejection. A tuned RF stage helps here.
Getting the bandwidth right is another issue. AM isn't a high fidelity medium and there's no capture effect suppressing interference from weak signals on adjacent channels. A fairly IF narrow bandwidth is desirable. A lower If frequency is better if you want a narrow bandwidth.
With an RF stage tuned on both its input and output, the tradeoffs made 262.5 kHz a good compromise. Without that extra stage, 455 kHz was a better compromise.
Multiband domestic radios usually used 455 kHz (although I have one using 465), and suffered poor image rejection on shortwave despite tuned RF stages. A higher IF led to a wider bandwidth, particularly undesirable with the narrow shortwave channel spacing of 5 kHz, so 455 was the compromise. The tracking difficulties on MW weren't terribly consequential with an antenna better than an automotive whip.
